# custom pycharm plugin always disabled

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I tryed a very simple plugin (with just an AnAction), and when I run or deploy it the result is:

- On PyCharm SDK: The plugin is disabled.
- On Intellij Community Edition: it works as expected

PyCharm is my primary target, so I need it to works, but have no clue to debug it. I just see this in the logs of PyCharm, which show my plugin was indeed disabled:

```
2015-03-11 11:34:19,911 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,923 [     12]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PyCharm Community Edition (build #PC-139.1001, 07 Jan 2015 00:00) 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,923 [     12]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (3.11.10-25-desktop, amd64) 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,923 [     12]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.7.0_71-b14 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,923 [     12]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 24.71-b01 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,925 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/b/tools/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/b/java_error_in_PYCHARM_%p.log -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/b/tools/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/../lib/boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=PyCharm40 -Didea.platform.prefix=PyCharmCore -Didea.no.jre.check=true -Djb.restart.code=88 
2015-03-11 11:34:19,951 [     40]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 26 ms 
2015-03-11 11:34:20,148 [    237]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: KWin 
2015-03-11 11:34:21,047 [   1136]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 13 plugins initialized in 751 ms 
2015-03-11 11:34:21,047 [   1136]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: CVS Integration (11), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, IDEA CORE, IPython Notebook (0.1), Python ReStructureText Integration (VERSION), ReStructuredText Support (136.SNAPSHOT), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-03-11 11:34:21,047 [   1136]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: Markdown (0.9.7) 
2015-03-11 11:34:21,047 [   1136]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: Android View Client code helper (1.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark your plugin descriptor as compatible with IDEs other than IntelliJ IDEA, by adding the correct <depends> tag. See [the documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Plugin+Compatibility+with+IntelliJ+Platform+Products) for more information.